# How to set Kendo UI grid column widths programmatically

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I would like to set Kendo UI grid column widths programmatically. I am using the following code:

```
function setColumnWidths(grid, options) {
    for (var i = 0; i < options.columns.length; i++) {
        grid.columns[i].width = options.columns[i].width;
    }
}
```

When debugging in chrome after the statements executed, grid.columns[i].width seems to be appropriately set to the new value, however nothing changes in the GUI, the column widths remain the same.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've ended with this. Dion's solution gave me starting idea about using colgroups, however that solution is limited to not having locked columns, what are in *different* colgroups.

Also note: I do not want to use grid.setOptions, because its limitations, ruining attached events and header (in case of using ASP MVC helper to render the grid)

```
function setColumnWidths(grid, options) {
    var lockedCount = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < options.columns.length; i++) {
        if (options.columns[i].hasOwnProperty('locked')) {
            if (options.columns[i].locked) {
                lockedCount++;
            }
        }
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < options.columns.length; i++) {
        var width = options.columns[i].width;
        grid.columns[i].width = width;
        if (options.columns[i].hasOwnProperty('locked') && options.columns[i].locked) {
            $("#grid .k-grid-header-locked").find("colgroup col").eq(i).width(width);
            $("#grid .k-grid-content-locked").find("colgroup col").eq(i).width(width);

        } else {
            $("#grid .k-grid-header-wrap").find("colgroup col").eq(i-lockedCount).width(width);
            $("#grid .k-grid-content").find("colgroup col").eq(i - lockedCount).width(width);
        }
    }
    // Hack to refresh grid visual state
    grid.reorderColumn(1, grid.columns[0]);
    grid.reorderColumn(1, grid.columns[0]);
}
```

Comment: The JQuery for finding the col might not be correct anymore.  I just had to do something like this and mine ended up like this: $("#grid .k-grid-header .k-grid-header-wrap").find...

Comment: how using this function?!! @Echostorm

Answer (score 9):

You need to change grid's width through its element instead of its definition. Kendo grid contains header and content, so you need to change two elements.

Use this code instead

```
$("#grid-id .k-grid-header-wrap").find("colgroup col").eq(xx).width(yy);
$("#grid-id .k-grid-content").find("colgroup col").eq(xx).width(yy);
```

**[Sample](http://dojo.telerik.com/@diondirza/UtoJI)**

Comment: Thanks. I supposed we have a grid API and object model instead manipulating html... anyway it works.

Comment: A reminder: remember to skip hidden columns as they don't have their `col` tags. That is In case you try to apply this to all columns