# Horizontal scroll for a Kendo Grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a Kendo Grid inside a Kendo Window. How can I enable its horizontal scrolling using wrappers?

I've tried anything, but none of them worked. The last thing I tried was surrounding the Grid with a width-limited `div`.

Comment: Maybe because my Grid is inside a Kendo Window?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried using frozen column, I prefer use this feature if I have a lot of columns to be displayed.

**[Demo Section](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/frozen-columns)**

Comment: Thanks Dion, it's closer to what I want. But why does it hide the locked columns? And the second issue is that all columns are on one side, unless I drag them away.

Comment: There are 2 attributes for this feature, `locked` and `lockable`. `locked` columns will be on the left side (full open column), otherwise will be on the right side half hidden with horizontal scrollbar. if `lockable` then the column can be locked or not (can be dragged to left side or right side), not `lockable` means column stay on the right side.

Comment: Is there anyway I can set `width` property for all of the column? Do you know their selector?

Comment: You can find my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30150168/how-to-set-kendo-ui-grid-column-widths-programmatically/30159702#30159702)

Answer (score 7):

Apply Scrollable() and give Width for each columns and then if the total width exceeds the width of the grid the horizontal scrollbar will appear.

Reference

[Scrolling](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/walkthrough#scrolling)

[Kendo Grid Horizontal Scroll bar](http://www.telerik.com/forums/kendo-grid-horizontal-scroll-bar)

Comment: I set min-width like this: `#MyGrid{ min-width: 700px;}`. But it doesn't work. Should I set width for every single column? Any better solution? I have several grids and each one has about 15 columns.

Comment: I think you need to give that because the columns will autofit if you didn't

Comment: Don't forget to set the height to `"auto"` if you don't need vertical scrolling: `.Scrollable(s => s.Enabled(true).Height("auto"))`

Answer (score 2):

Another solution here could be using 'table-responsive' from bootstrap.
For example:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
   <div id="grid"></div>
</div>
```

and in the declaration of the kendogrid something like this:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
     dataSource: dataAjax.Rotation,
     scrollable: false,
});
```

Answer (score 2):

**Simple Solution to get the horizontal scrolling for a Kendo Grid**

If you want to get horizontal scrolling on the whole grid not on specific columns then you can try this.

Use `width: 'auto'`

It will show horizontal scrolling if grid's size is more than the container.

[Demo](https://dojo.telerik.com/adaBUCIQ)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with Angular 12. Adding `[scrollable]="true"` to the kendo-grid solved my issue.